# Book about winged boy who befriends two children?

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I read this book when I was younger. I think it was an older book, but I’m not sure. In the book, a brother and a sister live with a mom who works all the time. They meet a boy with wings / who can fly. He takes them to a sky kingdom (or something like that) and they meet a lady who makes fabric out of the night sky. Does anyone know what this book is? I would really appreciate it! Thanks!!! :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What year was this?  Do you remember what the cover looked like?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the novel ['Skellig' by David Almond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellig)?

From wikipedia:

> 10-year-old Michael and his family have recently moved into a house. He and his parents are nervous, as his new baby sister was born earlier than expected and may not live because of a heart condition. When Michael goes into the garage, he finds a strange emaciated creature hidden amid all the boxes, debris and dead insects. Michael assumes that he is a homeless person, but decides to look after him and gives him food.
>
> Meanwhile, his friends from school become more and more distant as
> Michael stops attending school and spends less time with them. He
> meets a girl named Mina from across the road and over the course of
> the story they become close. Mina is home-schooled and enjoys nature,
> birds, drawing and the poems of William Blake. Often drawing or
> sculpting at home, she invites Michael to join in. She takes care of
> some baby birds who live in her garden and teaches Michael to hear
> their tiny sounds. Michael decides to introduce her to the strange
> creature. Michael's friends, Coot and Leaky, become skeptical about
> Michael and try to find out what he is hiding from them. Michael and
> Mina try to keep it a secret from them, and have to move "Skellig" to
> a safer space.
>
> The creature whom Michael had moved from the garage—revealing a pair
> of wings at his shoulders—introduces himself as "Skellig" to Michael
> and Mina.

Answer (score -2):

The Wind Boy by Ethel Cook Eliot

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Can you please [edit] your answer to add some details about this book so we can see how it matches the question?

Comment: Also while you're here, please check out our [tour] and take a look at the [help].